# Are there any third party tools that can read and/or analyze SQL Profiler trace (.trc) files

Tags: sql-server, trace

I have a .trc file from a trace that a DBA did on one of my databases. I don't have the SQL profiler tool installed on my PC so I can't view the contents and analyze the trace log. How do I read this file without SQL profiler installed on my PC?

Comment: Qure Profiler is great... It shows barchars and it's easy to see which queries your server is spending the most time processing. Just make sure you get a really big sample size (it's perfectly happy processing a 2GB trace file).  http://www.dbsophic.com/products/qure-optimizer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Clear Trace](https://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/).

Kevin Kline gives a good summary of ClearTrace : [Graphical summary tool gives you clear look into trace/Profiler data](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/cleartrace)

Also if you want a basic profiler, look at [ExpressProfiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.

> ExpressProfiler (aka SqlExpress Profiler) is a simple but good enough replacement for SQL Server Profiler with basic GUI
>   No requirements, no installation. 
>   Can be used with both Express and non-Express editions of SQL Server 2005/2008/2008r2/2012 (including LocalDB)
>
> **Features**
>
> Tracing of basic set of events (Batch/RPC/SP:Stmt Starting/Completed, Audit login/logout - needed events can be selected) and columns (Event Class, Text Data,Login, CPU, Reads, Writes, Duration, SPID, Start/End time)
>   Filter on Duration
>   Copy all/selected event rows to clipboard in form of XML
>   Find in "Text data" column

Comment: Another tool that has been a life saver is RML http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8161

Comment: @AdamHaines Agreed, but it will steer up a whole new topic of SQL Nexus :-)

Comment: The "Kevin Kline" article is a broken link, and when I try to In ClearTrace, I can't import my trace file as the "Import Files" button is greyed out even if I specify a "First file".  Any pointers?

Answer (score 9):

I would probably import the trace to a table, for example:

```
USE MyDB
GO 
SELECT * INTO MyTraceTable FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('C:\Path\To\My\Trace\MyTrace.trc',    
DEFAULT)
```

If you don't have permissions to create a table, consider using a temporary table or installing SQL Server Express locally and importing the trace there.

Kin's answer (entered concurrently with mine) might be a better option, but I haven't tried ClearTrace yet.

Comment: Comparing normal profiler and clear trace functionality, in clear trace, you can tell how much CPU, disk reads and writes are done and it shows aggregates as well. I have used it and its a time saver when identifying bottlenecks. This is an online version http://www.tracetune.com/